# Show Selected Records fails to display in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select

I have been using ArcMap for a while and I just started having this issue (maybe because of a new laptop?). When I select items by Attributes the bottom of the table will say 97 out of 2000 selected, so I know that works. But when I click the show selected records, nothing is showing.

Does anyone have any ideas about what is going on?

Also when I go to try and create a layer from selected features, it's not working.

[image: shows select by attribute worked]

[image: shows selected records are blank, even tho 97 should be showing up]

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the below checks in one-by-one steps, and you can stop where it starts working.

Close ArcMap and do the below:

1. Use the FC to FC tool in ArcMap to export the layer as a new FGDB FC and test the same once again. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/using-the-feature-class-to-feature-class-tool.htm
2. Navigate to `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Esri\Desktop10.7\ArcMap\Templates` and rename the Normal.mxt file
3. Navigate to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming and rename the Esri Folder
4. Navigate to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local and rename the Esri Folder